# Javascript - Utilização do reduce

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, pessoal! Tudo bem com vocês? Espero que sim.

Estou começando meus estudos em Java Script, porém estou com dificuldade para implementar uma função usando o reduce.

O código é o seguinte:

```
const cartasFrete = []

const sequencia = {
    _id: 0,
    get id() { return this._id++}
}

/*const getCartaFrete = (id) => {
    const aux = cartasFrete.filter((cartaFrete) => {
        return cartaFrete.id === id
    })
    return aux[0]
}
*/

const criarCartaFrete = (local, destino, valorFrete,porcentagem) => {
    return {
        id: sequencia.id,
        local: local,
        destino: destino,
        valorFrete: valorFrete,
        porcentagem: porcentagem,
        getValorFrete() {
            return this.valorFrete
        },

        getPorcentagem() {
            return this.porcentagem
        },
        getInformacoes() {
            return `
            Local: ${this.local}
            Destino: ${this.destino}
            Valor do Frete: ${this.valorFrete}
            Porcentagem: ${this.porcentagem * 100}
            `


        }
    }
}

const salvarCartaFrete = (...cartaFrete) => {
    cartaFrete.forEach((valor,indice) =>{
        cartasFrete[indice] = valor
    })
}

// ------------------------------------------------------ ## --------------------------------------------------//

let valoresCartas = []

const calcularCarta = (idCartaFrete, peso) => {
    const valorCarta = cartasFrete[idCartaFrete].getValorFrete()
    const valorTotal = valorCarta * peso
    const valorAbastecimento = valorTotal * cartasFrete[idCartaFrete].getPorcentagem()
    const valorTroco = valorTotal - valorAbastecimento
    return {
        total: valorTotal,
        troco: valorTroco,
        abastecimento: valorAbastecimento
    }

}

 const salvarCalculos = (...calculos) => {
    calculos.forEach((valor,indice) =>{
        valoresCartas[indice] = valor
    })
}

const calcularTodasCartas = (array) => {
    let valorGeral = array.reduce((acumulador,atual)=>{
        return acumulador + atual.total
    })
    return valorGeral
}

// ------------------------------------------------------ ## --------------------------------------------------//

salvarCartaFrete(
    criarCartaFrete('PMI','PEMA', 10.5, 0.5),
    criarCartaFrete('PMI','FILIAL', 14, 0.5),
    criarCartaFrete('SARZEDO','VDL', 22, 0.4)
)

salvarCalculos(
    calcularCarta(0,22),
    calcularCarta(1, 18),
    calcularCarta(2, 17)
)


console.log(valoresCartas)
console.log(calcularTodasCartas(valoresCartas))
```

O código funciona direitinho, até eu usar a função "calcularTodasCartas" .

A ideia desta função é somar os valores de todas as Cartas frentes dentro do array "valores Cartas".

Exemplo:

Neste código ele gera o seguinte array de objetos:

```
[ { total: 231, troco: 115.5, abastecimento: 115.5 },
  { total: 252, troco: 126, abastecimento: 126 },
  { total: 374, troco: 224.4, abastecimento: 149.6 } ]
```

Quero pegar os valores das chaves "total" de todas as posições do array e somar e retornar o valor acumulado,

pegar os valores das chaves "troco"  e somar voltar o valor acumulado, pegar os valores do abastecimento e somar e voltar acumulado.

Exemplo:

Total: 231 + 252 + 374 = 857

Seguindo essa lógica, escrevi o seguinte código:

```
const calcularTodasCartas = (array) => {
        let valorGeral = array.reduce((acumulador,atual)=>{
            return acumulador + atual.total
        })
        return valorGeral
    }
```

Mas o resultado é o seguinte:

```
[object Object]252374
```

Poderiam me dar uma luz?

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resposta**

Faltou você setar o valor inicial para 0:

```js
let array = [
  { total: 231, troco: 115.5, abastecimento: 115.5 },
  { total: 252, troco: 126, abastecimento: 126 },
  { total: 374, troco: 224.4, abastecimento: 149.6 } 
]

const calcularTodasCartas = (array) => {
    let valorGeral = array.reduce((acumulador, atual)=>{
        return acumulador + atual.total
    }, 0) // faltou setar o valor inicial
    return valorGeral;
}

console.log(calcularTodasCartas(array));
```

Assim, na primeira vez que rodar, ele irá fazer `(0 + { total: 231})`, o que resulta em `0 + 287`, depois `(287 + { total: 252 })`, o que resulta em `287 + 252`, na terceira vez `539 + { total: 374 }`, o que resulta em `539 + 374`, e por aí vai.

**O que deu errado?**

Do jeito anterior, você estava somando um objeto, no caso o `acumulador` com a o valor da propriedade `atual.total`, por isso dava aquele resultando com `[object Object]`, ao setar o valor inicial para 0, o `acumulador`, passar a ser `0`, como você pode ver no exemplo abaixo:

```js
let array = [
  { total: 231, troco: 115.5, abastecimento: 115.5 },
  { total: 252, troco: 126, abastecimento: 126 },
  { total: 374, troco: 224.4, abastecimento: 149.6 } 
]

// EXEMPLO SEM VALOR INICIAL
const calcularTodasCartasSemValorInicial = (array) => {
    let valorGeral = array.reduce((acumulador, atual)=>{
        console.log(acumulador);
        return acumulador + atual.total
    })
    return valorGeral;
}

// EXEMPLO COM VALOR INICIAL
const calcularTodasCartasComValorInicial = (array) => {
    let valorGeral = array.reduce((acumulador, atual)=>{
        console.log(acumulador);
        return acumulador + atual.total
    }, 0)
    return valorGeral;
}

console.log("Sem valor inicial: ", calcularTodasCartasSemValorInicial(array));
console.log("Com valor inicial: ", calcularTodasCartasComValorInicial(array));
```

Comment: Funcionou direitinho! Fiquei horas ontem e não encontrava o erro kkkkk muito obrigado!

Comment: Dá inclusive para fazer as 3 somas no mesmo reduce, inicializando o acumulador com `{total: 0, troco: 0, abastecimento: 0}` e somando assim `return {total: acumulador.total + atual.total, troco: acumulador.troco + atual.troco, abastecimento: acumulador.abastecimento + atual.abastecimento}`

Comment: Realmente, mas se eu fizer dessa forma eu não preciso setar o valor inicial como parâmetro no reduce, certo?